# volatile and const volatile std::tuple and std::get

Tags: c++, c++11

Looking at the C++11 standard. I can see that specialization of `std::tuple_size` and `std::tuple_element` are provided for `volatile` and `const volatile` tuple.

```
template <size_t I, class T> class tuple_element<I, volatile T>;
template <size_t I, class T> class tuple_element<I, const volatile T>;

template <class T> class tuple_size<volatile T>;
template <class T> class tuple_size<const volatile T>;
```

But `std::get` do no offer specialization for `volatile` or `const volatile` tuple.

I tried the following code on GCC.4.8.1

```
volatile std::tuple<int, int> a(1, 1);
std::cout << "a<0>=" << std::get<0>(a) << "\n";
```

I get error: `no matching function for call to 'get(volatile std::tuple<int, int>&)'`

So if I understand I can create (const) volatile tuples but I can not access their elements.

Is this an expected behavior or an oversight ?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Doesn't work on GCC 4.9 either, fwiw.

Comment: `const volatile` strikes me as a weird combination. Anyone know of a legitimate use of it?

Comment: @Cameron hardware registers that shouldn't be written to but can be changed under you, for instance.

Comment: Pretty much no standard library type outside of `<atomic>` works when `volatile`-qualified. `tuple` is no exception.

Answer (score 4):

This is not only the case for `std::get` but also for the [relational operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp) or [`swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/swap2).
Why does `swap` not support volatile tuples then? Because no [move constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple) of `tuple` takes volatile tuples. Same goes for the [assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator%3D). Actually, when considering the standard library in its entirety, almost no class or template provides overloads for volatile objects<sup>1</sup>. Maybe it would be to much of a hassle in standardization and implementation; Or perhaps it's was regarded nonsensical to have volatile class objects. In either case, volatile tuples are currently quite unusable and adding a `get` overload for them would, with respect to the current state of the interface, be inconsistent.

Using `volatile tuple` as a **type** (and not an object) is not per se problematic and could be useful. That, and the fact that pretty much every single other type trait in the standard library is also specialized for all cv-qualifiers, lead to `tuple_element` and `tuple_size` supporting it.

---

<sup>1</sup> One can easily check this by searching for `volatile` in the C++ standard from clause 17 on. One will find that no function (template) apart from the ones for atomics in clause 29 is overloaded for volatile parameters.